# Nuxt sometimes not navigate to error page

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

There are client errors that show the error layout but not navigate to error page.

For example if I will call in created to not defined method ddd()

It will throw

```
client.js:103 ReferenceError: ddd is not defined
```

but still stay on same route, I want all my errors to navigate to /error route

Answer (score 1):

Calling a non-defined method is not a **navigation** issue, so you don't get redirected to the error page because there is no navigation involved, seems legit.

If you try `this.$router.push('/this-route-does-not-exist-klj123kl4j1ojaskldjl1234')`, it will probably lead you to an error page.

Comment: but the error layout is till used for not navigation errors, "The error page is a page component which is always displayed when an error occurs (that is not thrown on the server-side)" so the layout is used without route than how the NuxtLink to home page supposed to rerender

Comment: From what you're giving us here, I don't have enough context to give a proper answer. Please provide a [repro] with your actual issue. @nadav